# next() and nextall >

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following structure

```
<h2> title </h2>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>

<h2> title 2 </h2>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

I am using `Jquery.load()` function and it looks like so:

```
<script> $('#result').load('http://www.mysite/page h2:contains(title)'  ) ;
```

This works to get me to the h2.. but I can't seem to get to the NEXT element.. do they have to match? ie do they all have to be the same tags. I tried:

```
<script> $('#result').load('http://www.mysite/page h2:contains(title).next(li:lt(3)'  ) ;
```

but it does not work.. I need to select 3 li's FOLLOWING each specified h2

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are using a jquery method within css selectors.  That is invalid css.  Secondly, this seemed to work for me:

```
$('#result').load('http://www.mysite/page h2:contains(title) + ul > li:nth-child(-n+3)');
```

This css will select the adjacent `ul`, the direct descendant of that `ul`, the `li`s, and of those, the first three.

Comment: Perfect.... THANKS! Why would it be invalid css it's jquery, I am not selecting any ids? only html tags? I mean isn't that what "contains" is for?

Comment: also, wouldn't the "+" mean the h2 AND the UL.. not the UL AFTER the h2???? and so what does ">" mean? Thanks again.

Comment: @user5288 The `+` means 'adjacent element'.  The `>` symbol means 'direct descendant'.  As to to the workings of jQuery, I'll check the source for you, but it only takes a css selector, reading from the documentation, not to mention that a jquery selector won't work within a string.

Comment: ok that makes sense. I was trying the next() or the nextall but that seemed to work with similar elements.. that is if they were all li's It would have worked. I thought the (contains) allowed you to select other elements that are not css elements...

Comment: @user5288 The selector is passed to [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L177), which, while `.find()` can take a jquery object, what is passed to it is a string, and the string is not `eval()`'d(which would be dangerous all the same anyway).

Comment: thanks for the time :) I am sorry but I am not that advanced..

are you saying I am better of using find().. or

Comment: @Deedub I am not saying that, I would suggest you stick with the pure css solution for now, as it's less the browser has to do.  I was just checking the source for you to find how the selector passed in the url string was treated, and pass on that information.

Comment: K. But what is confusing me is that I thought I was using .load(), which is jquery right? Or is the end portion of what you added css? Sorry. Still learning.

Comment: @Deedub `.load()` is indeed jquery, and what you passed after the space in the url string is a css selector.  Jquery uses itself in its own code, so it then splits the string at the space, and passes the second part of it(the css) into `.find()` to find the elements in the loaded html.

Comment: Ok so ul > li:nth-child(-n+3). Is actually a css selector function and not a jquery function?

Comment: @Deedub Yes, that's pure css.  See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).

Comment: I have no idea what I just read :( thanks so much for your help. Have to learn much.

Comment: @Deedub I suppose I could, it just depends on the complexity of the project.  Although I'd like to think I have a good understanding of javascript/jquery/php/sql, there are much better people out there than me.

Comment: Ok Sounds good. Nothing major though. Am learning as I go. Sometimes it takes me too long to figure something out where someone like you could do it in 20mins....

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
$('#result').load('http://www.mysite/page h2:contains(title) + ul li:nth-child(1),li:nth-child(2)');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dfUH8/11/)**

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @Kundan Singh Chouhan's answer, the exact same thing would just be done in CSS without any JavaScript at all.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dfUH8/12/

```
h2 + ul li:nth-child(1),
li:nth-child(2){
    background-color: red;
}
```

Although, this will only work in newer browsers that support CSS3 where as the JavaScript version will work everywhere.

Comment: thanks! well how I would need it to work each specifically for every h2 since they will be called in different places depending on what's inside the h2, hence the (contains).

Comment: Well, if that is the case you will most certainly need to use JavaScript then and not a pure CSS solution.

Comment: Yea. Just hacking it for now. There's a lot I don't get.